# Android speed up install time during development

Tags: android, installation, build-time

I have a rather large Android game that I'm working on and making small changes in code is killing my productivity.

If I make a small change, it has to re-upload and install a 15mb package every time I hit run. I'm running on a real device and it's still takes a good deal of time.

Granted it's only about 1 minute, but one minute to load, 3 to test, 1 minute to change and then the cycle starts over. That's 1/5 of my time just waiting.

Is there a way to choose to just push code changes and not asset/resources?

Comment: use the emulator for minor changes, and only test on device after major changes

Comment: I really doubt that u can do anything about that since, install is an install. Its better that u plan better and make bigger chunk of changes so u spend lesser time waiting for installs. Though it will be nice to know if anything can be done about it.

Comment: The emulator is too slow to use. The time I spend running 5 fps with a game engine on the emulator is more than my install time.

Cest la vis. Worth a try. Temporarly switching to storing resources on the SD card during development might be an option. Synching with a web server on launch to make sure resources are up to date.

Might be too much work, however. It was worth a try, I wasn't expecting an answer, just hoping.

Comment: If the resources are taking up most the space, and you're only testing changes in your code, it could be possible on a rooted device with a decent busybox to remove the classes.dex file from the newly compiled apk and push it to the device through adb then use the phone's shell with busybox zip to replace only that file (a la ninjamorph.apk)... It could easily be done in a shell/cygwin script. No guarantees it would work... kinda just thinking out loud